# How come my cookies are not being set in the frontend of my app using express-session and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, express-session

I am programming with a MERN stack and I ran into a brick wall when using express-session. It seems that I can't set cookies when my frontend `localhost:3000` hit the endpoints in my backend `localhost:8080`. Cookies set perfectly fine when I'm at `localhost:8080` and I hit my endpoint in my backend `localhost:8080`. How can I solve this issue? I want react to be able to set the `httpOnly` cookie when I register my user or regenerate the cookie when I log in or destroy the session when I logout. etc... I am not exactly sure if this is a cors issue I'm dealing with. Just a side note these cookies are being set because I have tested them. the issue is I am not able to see the cookies being set from my frontend.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const session = require('express-session')
const cors = require('cors')

const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session)
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const config = require('config')

const server = express();

server.set('trust proxy', 1);
server.use(express.json());
server.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
server.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  credentials: true
}))

server.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Set-Cookie");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, HEAD, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
  if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || config.get("mongo_db_key"),
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  })
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB Connected"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))

server.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false ,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  },
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
  })
}))

const auth = require('./routes/API/auth');

server.use('/account', auth);

server.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port: ${PORT}`));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't set a cookie across domains(which includes protocol, domain), with the exception being you can set a cookie for a higher level domain that is shared by subdomains  (eg `Domain=mozilla.org` then `developer.mozilla.org` will get the cookie).  When it comes to cookies that maintain a user session they are almost always set by the server instead of the client(Client side access to session cookies should be restricted for security issues).

In the most basic pattern you would only have a single backend server that would serve your react application as well as provide the backend for simplicity.

Comment: there is no way for this to happen? is there an alternative I can do? I do not want to store my auth key in local storage. I want everything to be operated at the server level so users cant modify anything.

Comment: You should not need to manage your session since it is being managed by the express-session middleware. The issue is you have multiple domains involved.  You should either use a proxy or serve everything from one application.